# WSO2 Identity server - Restricting access to SSO service

Tags: wso2, saml, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

My understanding of SAML and WSO2 is very basic so sorry in advance. I'm wondering if access to a SSO service can be restricted to a subset of users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can restrict the access to a SAML SSO Service Provider to a subset of users. This is an authorization requirement indeed. When the service provider redirects the user to the Identity Provider (in this case to the WSO2 Identity Server), the service provider can request claims about the user from the Identity Server (claims such as Role, Email, Age, Country etc). Then after successful authentication of the user at the Identity Provider, the Identity Provider will send those claim values to the SSO Service Provider along with the SAML Response message. The SSO Service provider can read these claims and can decide if should let the user access the service or not. (For example by looking at the Role claim, if use has a particular role then SSO Service Provider allows the user, if not refuse)

Comment: Thanks! So the WSO2 Identity Server can't return a 'Invalid login' for a subset of users, i.e the Identity Server only checks for identities and it is the SAML SSO Service Provider's responsibility to handle access based on claim values contained within the SAML Response Message? BTW your answers across(around?) the web are very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Kurent. Yes, the service provider is the one who should decide to grant or deny the access to the service based on the response sent by the identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think that according the SAML specification, Identity provider can return error state. It has an element in SAMLResponse dedicated to this -> Status. But WSO2 Identity Server (up to 5.0.0), as far as I know, doesn't automatically support this behavior. One should change WSO2 authorization code to achieve this behavior...

Source:
[SAML 2.0 Overview](http://xml.coverpages.org/SAMLv20CoreWD-v05.pdf) - line 1131, chapter: 3.2.2.2 Element

```
<samlp:Response
...<saml:Issuer>https://idp.example.org/SAML2</saml:Issuer>
<samlp:Status>
<samlp:StatusCode
**Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>**
</samlp:Status>
<saml:Assertion  ...
```

Instead of Success IdP can return:
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:AuthnFailed
or similar... see:
[SAML2.0 handling SSO error](https://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/saml-dev/200901/msg00021.html)